# Who first defined the "equal-delta" or "delta over equal" ($\triangleq$) symbol?

Tags: mathematics, reference-request, terminology, notation

The symbol $\triangleq$ is sometimes used in mathematics (and physics) for a definition. It is instantiated for instance in the [Unicode Character 'DELTA EQUAL TO' (U+225C)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/225c/index.htm).
The notation  $t \triangleq m$ (generally) means: "$t$ is defined to be $m$" or "$t$ is equal by definition to $m$" (often under certain conditions).

In a similar sense, some use $:=$ or  $=:$ (see for instance [Symbols based on equality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols#Symbols_based_on_equality)). Yet, this *Delta variant* is more important to me.

The SE. Maths post [What is meant by the delta equivalent sign?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289339/what-is-meant-by-the-delta-equivalent-sign) proposes a slight distinction (not crystal-clear to me) between the above similar senses:

> Sometimes it is used with the slightly different meaning of "equal by definition", to underline the difference w.r.t. "$:=$ " which is the definition itself.
> i.e.
>
> $$
> a:=3;\\
> 5+a \triangleq 5 + 3 = 8 
> $$

I always took for granted that the $\Delta$ stood for letter "D", i.e. for the  initial of "**definition**". Indeed, one sometimes finds $\overset{\mathrm{def}}{=}$ too. In German apparently, one also uses $≙$ (*Entspricht-Zeichen*, with Unicode U+2259).

Based on these prior hints, my questions are as follows:

- Who introduced this dual symbol first in science, and where (which source)?
- What motivated the Greek $\Delta$ notation? The abbreviation of some word, a symbol (why not a latin notation)?
- Why not merge the lower bar of the Delta with the upper bar of the equal sign, to save some ink, and create a lighter symbol?

References: the symbol itself was already discussed in StackExchange:

- SE.math: [What is meant by the delta equivalent sign?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289339/what-is-meant-by-the-delta-equivalent-sign)
- SE.tex: [Delta-equal to symbol](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/163829/delta-equal-to-symbol)

Comment: This notation seems very strange, as it suggests symmetry between the definiens and the definiendum. I am more used to := or =:, with the colon on the side of the definiendum.

Comment: Mathsym http://jeff560.tripod.com/mathsym.html has only $=_{\mathrm{Def}}$ (from 1894) but not the Delta version.

Comment: @MargaretFriedland The asymmetry is given by what is _before_ the symbol and what is _after_ the symbol. Thus $A \triangleq B$ always means "_A is defined to be B_".

Comment: @MargaretFriedland, I am sympathetic to your objection, and, in fact, would go so far as to object somewhat to the $:=$ usage, since it lends itself to typos so easily. Rather, I'd strongly prefer that the _context_ clarify any asymmetry (such as a definition or notational abbreviation) in a mathematical equality. (Mathematicians seem unlikely to take these asymmetries as seriously as programmers may, so I don't necessarily trust them!)

Comment: The symmetric way understand it is to read it as "this equality holds by definition". From that perspective there is no "definiens" or "definiendum".

Comment: Maybe a "remnant asymetry" resides in the convention of writing the "definiendum" (thanks for the words) on the left-hand side

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is really a comment rather than a full answer.

Florian Cajori's encyclopedic tome *A History of Mathematical Notations* does not seem to discuss this symbol specifically; the closest thing is the following remark in Section 269:

> L. Gustave du Pasquier (*Comptes Rendus du Congrès International des Mathématicians* (Strasbourg, 22–30 Septembre 1920), p. 164) in discussing general complex numbers employs the sign of
> double equality $\overset{\displaystyle =}{=}$ to signify “equal by definition.”

I checked MathSciNet, and the review of the 1953 paper "Zwei Klassen von Flächen, deren Bestimmung von einem Integral der Telegraphengleichung abhängt" by Hans Jonas (MR0058259) uses the notation $=_{\text{def}}$ (but note that Jonas's paper itself does not use that notation). This seems to be the earliest occurrence of $=_{\text{def}}$ or $\overset{\text{def}}=$ in MathSciNet.  But I do not have access to a print version to verify that the notation was actually used back in the 1953 edition of Mathematical Reviews.

Comment: I have been waiting for a long time, let me validate yours, until...

Comment: After I posted this, I noticed [Gerald Edgar's comment](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/5166/who-first-defined-the-equal-delta-or-delta-over-equal-triangleq-symbol/13458#comment8139_5166) which points to an 1894 use of $=_{\rm Def}$ to mean [equal by definition](https://jeff560.tripod.com/set.html).